# getting image extension in Twig Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

Am not very familiar with twig, am trying to get an image extention, but am not sure how to do this in twig ,in php it's very easy using string functions such as substr and indexof or with the following:  ext=pathinfo('/testdir/dir2/image.gif', PATHINFO_EXTENSION), i don't want to code it in controller and pass it to twig as parameter,instead i want to extract it directly in the twig layout,so how am going to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [Twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html), that will contain

namespace YourApp\AcmeBundle\Twig;

```
class MyTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

public function getFilters(){
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('ext', array($this, 'ext')),
    );
}

public function ext($filepath){
    $ext = pathinfo($filepath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    return $ext;
}

}
```

Comment: as a biginner i will avoid this solution because if i have to work with twig extension then i have to know how to work with scopes because extensions are not lazily loaded. as i read in the article you gave me, thanks anyway at least i have an idea about it :)

Answer (score 35):

You can get file extension by this way

```
{{ "filename.txt"|split('.')|last }}
```

Comment: You are awesome.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use Twig's [slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) filter.

For example, if the path to your image file is `imgSrc`, then `imgSrc|slice(-4)` will give you the last 4 characters of the filename (eg. `.gif`, `.jpg`, `jpeg`).

Answer (score 1):

In twig, use the split filter. see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html

you can also simply get the extension in the controller and pass it to twig.